# Add new column with one value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```py
a = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10, 11, 12]], columns=['a','b','c'])
a
Out[234]: 
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
3  10  11  12
```

I want to add a column with only the last row as the mean of the last 2 values of column `c`. Something like:

```
    a   b   c   d
0   1   2   3  NaN
1   4   5   6  NaN
2   7   8   9  NaN
3  10  11  12 mean(9,12)
```

I tried this but the first part gives an error:

```py
a['d'].iloc[-1] = a.c.iloc[-2:].values.mean()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may set `d` column beforehand (to ensure assignment):

```
In [100]: a['d'] = np.nan

In [101]: a['d'].iloc[-1] = a.c.iloc[-2:].mean()

In [102]: a
Out[102]: 
    a   b   c     d
0   1   2   3   NaN
1   4   5   6   NaN
2   7   8   9   NaN
3  10  11  12  10.5
```

Comment: `.iloc` is how this should be done. `.loc` will break when not a `RangeIndex`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) to assign at a single row/column label pair:

```
ix = a.shape[0]
a.at[ix-1,'d'] = a.loc[ix-2:ix, 'c'].values.mean()

    a   b   c     d
0   1   2   3   NaN
1   4   5   6   NaN
2   7   8   9   NaN
3  10  11  12  10.5
```

---

Also note that [chained indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) (what you're doing with `a.c.iloc[-2:]`) is explicitly discouraged in the docs, given that pandas sees these operations as separate events, namely two separate calls to  `__getitem__`, rather than a single call using a nested tuple of slices.

Comment: My experience is that chained **assignment** is the problematic one. There's nothing wrong with chained **selection** `a.c.iloc[-2:]`, it's just problematic when you chain things on the left hand side.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean in terms of it being problematic, it is mentioned though that it unnecessarily performs two calls to `__getitem__` @ALollz

Answer (score 1):

We can use `.loc`, `.iloc` & `np.mean`

```
a.loc[a.index.max(), 'd'] = np.mean(a.iloc[-2:, 2])

    a   b   c     d
0   1   2   3   NaN
1   4   5   6   NaN
2   7   8   9   NaN
3  10  11  12  10.5
```

Or just using `.loc` and `np.mean`:

```
a.loc[a.index.max(), 'd'] = np.mean(a.loc[a.index.max()-1:, 'c'])

    a   b   c     d
0   1   2   3   NaN
1   4   5   6   NaN
2   7   8   9   NaN
3  10  11  12  10.5
```